# mssql compare 2 fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

hey guys i have a problem where i can't find an answer on

i have 2 sql tables from different database

database "**common**" 
table `allUsers`

```
id     name         id customer
aa1_1   john wick       null
aa1_2   elvis       null
aa1_3   natasha     null
aa1_4   jhonny bravo    1
aa1_5   shakespear  null
bb1_1   jack sparrow    null
bb1_2   jackie chan null
bb1_3   vin diesel  null
bb1_4   kees        null
bb1_5   william     2
cc1_1   trump       null
cc1_2   barack      null
```

database "**confic**"
table `customers`

```
id  name            prefix
1   anti-alcohol    aa1_
2   barbarian       bb1_ 
3   concuerer       cc1_
```

how can i make sure the numbers are filled by the right customer id 
from `customers` ?

Comment: You mean create a CONSTRAINT or UPDATE allUser table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS sql support join between different db if they are on the same server.

```
UPDATE a
FROM common.dbo.allUsers a
JOIN confic.dbo.customers c
  ON LEFT(a.id, 4) = c.prefix
SET a.[id customer] = c.id
```

Comment: I think it should be:  `ON LEFT(a.id, 4) = c.prefix`